# Should I free the fstab pointer returned by getfsent?

Tags: fstab, c

```
#include <fstab.h>

struct fstab *getfsent(void);
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getfsent.3.html

`getfsent` reads a line from `/etc/fstab` file and return a variable of type `struct fstab*`. Do I need to free it? Or it's managed by someone else? If it's managed by someone else, why isn't the return type `const struct fstab*`? I check the reference above but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: It's probably implementation-dependent, but the original is [**`static`**](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getfsent&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for glibc, you shouldn't. The [source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/fstab.c;h=8fbe3c7767dfb1c9bb2a3b59f7423ca462abe01e;hb=HEAD) indicates that the pointer is to a member of an internal state struct, so it's not something you can directly free.

The [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/fstab.html) also hint at this:

> To read the entire content of the of the `fstab` file the GNU C
>   Library contains a set of three functions which are designed in the
>   usual way.

The "usual" way here being something like [`getpwent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html#RETURN_VALUE):

> The return value may point to a static area, and may be overwritten
>   by subsequent calls to `getpwent()`, `getpwnam(3)`, or `getpwuid(3)`.  (Do 
>   not pass the returned pointer to `free(3)`.)

Also, the glibc docs specifically for `getfsent`:

> The function returns a pointer to a variable of type `struct fstab`.
>   This variable is shared by all threads and therefore this function is
>   not thread-safe. If an error occurred getfsent returns a `NULL`
>   pointer.

That that variable is shared is a strong indication you should not mess with memory management.

If you want to free the resources, use `endfsent()`, which will clear the internal state.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware `glibc` has such comprehensive documentation. It rocks!